# Which Angular provider for function syntax?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I have a provider named `lookup`. It's used like this:

```
.controller('lookupCtrl', ['lookup', function(lookup) {
    this.values = lookup('monkey');
}]);
```

What is `lookup`? Is it a `service()`? Is it a `factory()`? A `value()`?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it can be any of those.

lookup could be a value if you created a regular, plain-old JavaScript object and then used the Value provider, naming your object "lookup".   Even though a value is typically a simple type, it could be an object, and this would work.

lookup could also be a factory if you used the factory provider, in which case, you specify a function which returns an object.   The object you return is the exact same object that's injected in any routine like the above that requests 'lookup'

And finally, lookup can also be an angular service.   If you did that, the service provider would specify a function that returns a "newable" object.   So the thing you return will be a function which Angular will "new", and the result of that will be passed to anyone who requests a 'lookup' instance.   Note that, even in this case, Angular instantiates your service one and only one time.   The difference between factory and service is subtle.   Think of a service returning a "class" that angular instantiates once and reuses that one instance.  And a factory uses the object that you returned to angular.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **"D: All of the above"**

**As a service:**

```
.service('myService', function(){

  return function(someParam){
     console.log(someParam);
  };

});
```

**As a factory:**

```
.factory('myFactory', function(){

  return function(someParam){
     console.log(someParam);
  };

});
```

**As a value:**

```
.value('myValue', function(){
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZqFH3BMPzCBX19nnPDz?p=preview)... look at the console output.